# Solve Zookeeper NoSuchMethodError from Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am facing this error when i run /bin/kafka-server-start.sh /config/server.properties

```
2020-02-27T13:23:34,540 ERROR [main] kafka.server.KafkaServer - [KafkaServer id=0] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.multi(Ljava/lang/Iterable;Lorg/apache/zookeeper/AsyncCallback$MultiCallback;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.send(ZooKeeperClient.scala:239) ~[kafka_2.12-2.4.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.$anonfun$handleRequests$2(ZooKeeperClient.scala:161) ~[kafka_2.12-2.4.0.jar:?]
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23) ~[scala-library-2.12.10.jar:?]
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:253) ~[kafka_2.12-2.4.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inReadLock(CoreUtils.scala:259) ~[kafka_2.12-2.4.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.$anonfun$handleRequests$1(ZooKeeperClient.scala:161) ~[kafka_2.12-2.4.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.$anonfun$handleRequests$1$adapted(ZooKeeperClient.scala:157) ~[kafka_2.12-2.4.0.jar:?]
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62) ~[scala-library-2.12.10.jar:?]
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55) ~[scala-library-2.12.10.jar:?]
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49) ~[scala-library-2.12.10.jar:?]
    at kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient.handleRequests(ZooKeeperClient.scala:157) ~[kafka_2.12-2.4.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.retryRequestsUntilConnected(KafkaZkClient.scala:1691) ~[kafka_2.12-2.4.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.retryRequestsUntilConnected(KafkaZkClient.scala:1678) ~[kafka_2.12-2.4.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.retryRequestUntilConnected(KafkaZkClient.scala:1673) ~[kafka_2.12-2.4.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$CheckedEphemeral.create(KafkaZkClient.scala:1743) ~[kafka_2.12-2.4.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.checkedEphemeralCreate(KafkaZkClient.scala:1720) ~[kafka_2.12-2.4.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.registerBroker(KafkaZkClient.scala:93) ~[kafka_2.12-2.4.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:270) [kafka_2.12-2.4.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:44) [kafka_2.12-2.4.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:84) [kafka_2.12-2.4.0.jar:?]
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala) [kafka_2.12-2.4.0.jar:?]
2020-02-27T13:23:34,549 INFO [main] kafka.server.KafkaServer - [KafkaServer id=0] shutting down
2020-02-27T13:23:34,556 INFO [main] kafka.network.SocketServer - [SocketServer brokerId=0] Stopping socket server request processors
2020-02-27T13:23:34,590 INFO [main] kafka.network.SocketServer - [SocketServer brokerId=0] Stopped socket server request processors
2020-02-27T13:23:34,606 INFO [main] kafka.server.ReplicaManager - [ReplicaManager broker=0] Shutting down
2020-02-27T13:23:34,610 INFO [main] kafka.server.ReplicaManager$LogDirFailureHandler - [LogDirFailureHandler]: Shutting down
2020-02-27T13:23:34,620 INFO [main] kafka.server.ReplicaManager$LogDirFailureHandler - [LogDirFailureHandler]: Shutdown completed
2020-02-27T13:23:34,623 INFO [main] kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager - [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 0] shutting down
2020-02-27T13:23:34,631 INFO [LogDirFailureHandler] kafka.server.ReplicaManager$LogDirFailureHandler - [LogDirFailureHandler]: Stopped
2020-02-27T13:23:34,631 INFO [main] kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager - [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 0] shutdown completed
2020-02-27T13:23:34,634 INFO [main] kafka.server.ReplicaAlterLogDirsManager - [ReplicaAlterLogDirsManager on broker 0] shutting down
2020-02-27T13:23:34,646 INFO [main] kafka.server.ReplicaAlterLogDirsManager - [ReplicaAlterLogDirsManager on broker 0] shutdown completed
2020-02-27T13:23:34,646 INFO [main] kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper - [ExpirationReaper-0-Fetch]: Shutting down
2020-02-27T13:23:34,774 INFO [ExpirationReaper-0-Fetch] kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper - [ExpirationReaper-0-Fetch]: Stopped
2020-02-27T13:23:34,774 INFO [main] kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper - [ExpirationReaper-0-Fetch]: Shutdown completed
2020-02-27T13:23:34,776 INFO [main] kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper - [ExpirationReaper-0-Produce]: Shutting down
2020-02-27T13:23:34,959 INFO [ExpirationReaper-0-Produce] kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper - [ExpirationReaper-0-Produce]: Stopped
2020-02-27T13:23:34,959 INFO [main] kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper - [ExpirationReaper-0-Produce]: Shutdown completed
2020-02-27T13:23:34,961 INFO [main] kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper - [ExpirationReaper-0-DeleteRecords]: Shutting down
2020-02-27T13:23:35,003 INFO [ExpirationReaper-0-DeleteRecords] kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper - [ExpirationReaper-0-DeleteRecords]: Stopped
2020-02-27T13:23:35,003 INFO [main] kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper - [ExpirationReaper-0-DeleteRecords]: Shutdown completed
2020-02-27T13:23:35,004 INFO [main] kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper - [ExpirationReaper-0-ElectLeader]: Shutting down
2020-02-27T13:23:35,012 INFO [ExpirationReaper-0-ElectLeader] kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper - [ExpirationReaper-0-ElectLeader]: Stopped
2020-02-27T13:23:35,013 INFO [main] kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper - [ExpirationReaper-0-ElectLeader]: Shutdown completed
2020-02-27T13:23:35,039 INFO [main] kafka.server.ReplicaManager - [ReplicaManager broker=0] Shut down completely
2020-02-27T13:23:35,042 INFO [main] kafka.log.LogManager - Shutting down.
2020-02-27T13:23:35,047 INFO [main] kafka.log.LogCleaner - Shutting down the log cleaner.
2020-02-27T13:23:35,048 INFO [main] kafka.log.LogCleaner - [kafka-log-cleaner-thread-0]: Shutting down
2020-02-27T13:23:35,050 INFO [kafka-log-cleaner-thread-0] kafka.log.LogCleaner - [kafka-log-cleaner-thread-0]: Stopped
2020-02-27T13:23:35,052 INFO [main] kafka.log.LogCleaner - [kafka-log-cleaner-thread-0]: Shutdown completed
2020-02-27T13:23:35,118 INFO [main] kafka.log.LogManager - Shutdown complete.
2020-02-27T13:23:35,120 INFO [main] kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient - [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closing.
2020-02-27T13:23:35,145 INFO [main] org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper - Session: 0x17085a21f120000 closed
2020-02-27T13:23:35,150 INFO [main] kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient - [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closed.
2020-02-27T13:23:35,151 INFO [main] kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper - [ThrottledChannelReaper-Fetch]: Shutting down
2020-02-27T13:23:35,152 INFO [main-EventThread] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - EventThread shut down
2020-02-27T13:23:35,156 INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Fetch] kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper - [ThrottledChannelReaper-Fetch]: Stopped
2020-02-27T13:23:35,159 INFO [main] kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper - [ThrottledChannelReaper-Fetch]: Shutdown completed
2020-02-27T13:23:35,159 INFO [main] kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper - [ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce]: Shutting down
2020-02-27T13:23:36,160 INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce] kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper - [ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce]: Stopped
2020-02-27T13:23:36,161 INFO [main] kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper - [ThrottledChannelReaper-Produce]: Shutdown completed
2020-02-27T13:23:36,161 INFO [main] kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper - [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Shutting down
2020-02-27T13:23:36,163 INFO [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request] kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper - [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Stopped
2020-02-27T13:23:36,163 INFO [main] kafka.server.ClientQuotaManager$ThrottledChannelReaper - [ThrottledChannelReaper-Request]: Shutdown completed
2020-02-27T13:23:36,167 INFO [main] kafka.network.SocketServer - [SocketServer brokerId=0] Shutting down socket server
2020-02-27T13:23:36,311 INFO [main] kafka.network.SocketServer - [SocketServer brokerId=0] Shutdown completed
2020-02-27T13:23:36,326 INFO [main] kafka.server.KafkaServer - [KafkaServer id=0] shut down completed
2020-02-27T13:23:36,329 ERROR [main] kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable - Exiting Kafka.
2020-02-27T13:23:36,337 INFO [kafka-shutdown-hook] kafka.server.KafkaServer - [KafkaServer id=0] shutting down
ERROR [main] kafka.server.KafkaServer - [KafkaServer id=0] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown
```

i am facing this problem when i start kafka server

Comment: Did you change anything in your properties?

Comment: no i just download kafka and start zookeeper server after that i started kafka server

Comment: What version of Kafka? What version of Zookeeper? What version of Java? What is your host OS?

Comment: i am using  kafka-2.4.0-src.tgz (asc, sha512) , i am using inbuilt zookeeper with kafka and my java version is java version "1.8.0_191"
my OS is centos

Comment: plz sir solve my this problem i have been facing this problem since last 20 days

Comment: Try Java 11 or 13. If you're using Linux, I'd suggest just using Docker